# Space between two images in outlook from email template made with HTML, CSS and Jinja

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, jinja2

[Problem in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDkEw.png)

I have two images in two different tables in an email template. Looks great and works well in everything else but Outlook. There is a tiny white space between the two images in two different TDs that I can not get rid of no matter what I try. The reason I'm doing this is because I want the top banner two look like one consistent image but only have an anchor tag on the logo. I couldn't achieve this any other way. Does anybody have any ideas?

Source code:

```
{% import 'delivery/email_templates/macros.html' as email %}
{% set paddingWidth = '32px' %}
{% set backgroundColor = 'white' %}

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div 
            bgcolor="#F5F5F5"
            style=
            "background: #F5F5F5;
            background-color: #F5F5F5;
            display: block; 
            font-family:'Helvetica', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            color: #333333;
            font-weight: normal; 
            padding: 1em 0;"
            >
            <table
                border="0" 
                cellpadding="0" 
                cellspacing="0"
                align="center"
                style=
                "{% block width %} 
                    width: 700px;
                {% endblock %} 
                margin: 0 auto; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding:0;"
                >
                <tr>
                    <td
                        style=
                        "width: 192px;
                        height: 119px;
                        border-collapse: collapse;"
                        >
                        <a 
                            href="#website of company">
                            <img 
                                src="#First image"/>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100%;">
                        <img src="#Second Image" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table
                border="0" 
                cellpadding="0" 
                cellspacing="0"
                align="center"
                style=
                "width: 700;
                margin: 0 auto; 
                border-collapse: collapse;"
                >
                <tr>
                    <td 
                        style=
                        "background-color: {{ backgroundColor }}; 
                        padding: 1em {{ paddingWidth }} 0 1em;
                        border-bottom: 2px solid #CDD6DA;"
                        >
                        <div style="margin-top:0;">
                            {% block body %}
                            {% endblock %}
                        </div>
                        {% block signature %}
                        {% if request.signature %}
                            {% macro signature_line(value, style=None) %}
                                {% if value %}
                                    {{ value }}
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endmacro %}
                        <table 
                            width="100%" 
                            border="0" 
                            cellpadding-top="0" 
                            style=
                            "font-family: 'Times New Roman', times, serif;" 
                            >
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td 
                                        style=
                                        "font-size: 16pt; 
                                        color: #000080;"
                                        >
                                        {{ signature_line(request.signature.name) }}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td 
                                        style=
                                        "font-size: 12px;"
                                        >
                                        #Company Name
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% if request.signature.address.address=="" %}
                                    <tr>
                                        <td 
                                            style=
                                            "font-size: 12px;"
                                            >
                                            {{ signature_line(request.signature.address.address) }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td 
                                            style=
                                            "font-size: 12px;"
                                            >
                                            {{ signature_line(request.signature.address.csz) }}
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                {% endif %}    
                                <tr>
                                    {% for phone in request.signature.phone_numbers %}
                                    <td 
                                        style=
                                        "font-size: 12px;"
                                        >
                                        {{ signature_line(phone) }}
                                    </td>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-size: 12px; padding-bottom:20px;">
                                        <a href="#Company Website</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endblock %}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tried messing with padding on every table and td. I tried cellpadding:0,cellspacing:0,margin:0,border:0. I've tried just doing a background image but that doesn't work in outlook. This is the only solution I've found that works across all email clients.